# Open File wp-admin/index.php

Tags: wordpress, archlinux

When I open the wp-admin/index.php file, I face this page:

```
' . __( 'Welcome to your WordPress Dashboard!' ) . '

'; $help .= '

' . __( 'The Dashboard is the first place you will come to every time you log into your site. It is where you will find all your WordPress tools. If you need help, just click the “Help” tab above the screen title.' ) . '
'; $screen = get_current_screen(); $screen->add_help_tab( array( 'id' => 'overview', 'title' => __( 'Overview' ), 'content' => $help, ) ); // Help tabs. $help = '
```

help me!.

Comment: download worpress and replace the index.php file

Comment: How do I do this in Arch Linux?

Comment: download wordpress from https://wordpress.org/download/ and replace index.php file

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-arch-linux